# SQL: Comparing <> Between Columns of Duplicate Table

Tags: sql

The Student schema is the following: Student(sID, sName, GPA)

Here is an example my teacher is using:

```
select sName
from Student S1
where GPA > all (select GPA from Student S2 
                 where S2.sID <> S1.sID);
```

I know the S2.sID <> S1.sID comparison is to make sure you do not double-count the same student. But I do not understand functionally how it works, and I do not know what the subquery returns. Can someone explain it to me?

```
sID    Name    GPA
01     Jon     4.0
02     Dan     3.0
03     Bill    3.6
```

Comment: "I know the S2.sID <> S1.sID comparison is to make sure you do not double-count the same student." No. You use that so you compare a student's GPA only with the GPA of all **other** students', not with his own (because his own GPA would be equal to itself, not `>`).

Comment: Sorry, I worded it poorly. That is what I meant. I updated the post to include an example table. I am still confused as to what the subquery would return.

Comment: @ypercube captured the gist. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: It would return "the GPA of all other students" except the current one. Think of the subquery as it is executing for every row of the `S1` table.

Comment: You're returning `sName` with maximum `GPA` in table `Student`. Execute the subquery to see what it returns, since you said you don't know what it does. Simply replace `S1.sID` with some `sID` you choose from `Student` table

Comment: "Think of the subquery as it is executing for every row of the S1 table." That helped me understand it, thanks! I thought that S2.sID <> S1.sID executed first, returning a column that compared both columns, as opposed to comparing the S2.sID column with a specific S1.sID value.

Comment: You hardly ever see `all()` used. Normally it is coded as `where GPA > (select max(GPA) from Student S2 where S2.sID <> S1.sID)`

Comment: What about: where GPA >= all (select GPA from Student)